# Python Pandas: NLTK Part of Speech Tagging for Entire Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, part-of-speech

I have the following sample data frame shown below.  It has been tokenized already.

```
No  category    problem_definition_stopwords
175 2521       ['coffee', 'maker', 'brewing', 'properly', '2', '420', '420', '420']
211 1438       ['galley', 'work', 'table', 'stuck']
912 2698       ['cloth', 'stuck']
572 2521       ['stuck', 'coffee']
```

I want to do part of speech tagging on this data frame.  Below is the beginning of my code.  It is erroring out:

```
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer 

train_text = state_union.raw(df['problem_definition_stopwords'])
```

Error

```
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

My desired result is below where 'XXX' is a tokenized word and after it is the part of speech (i.e. NNP):

[('XXX', 'NNP'), ('XXX', 'VBD'), ('XXX', 'POS')]

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I think you're confused about what `state_union.raw()` is. It is a collection (corpus) of documents of presidential state of the union addresses. You can't "call" it on your dataframe because your dataframe is not a document in the `state_union` corpus

Comment: oh gosh, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the  problem_definition_stopwords to a string and pass to nltk.sent_tokenize if you are trying to tokenize and get the POS with pos_tag.